# R.id.findViewById() do not see the id

Tags: java, android

this function do not see the id from which is in the activity_listing_music.xml i just want to make a simple list view activity to my music player but the java code can not see the id from the xml
so i hope somebody can help in this
aaa
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a

here is the codes:

```
package musync.demo_app;

<import is here>

public class ListingMusic extends AppCompatActivity {

    <useless code>
    public void doStuff() {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        getMusic();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.simple_List_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //music plater here
            }
        });
    }

    public void getMusic() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            do {
                String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
                String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
                arrayList.add(currentTitle + '\n' + currentArtist);
            } while(songCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }


}
```

and here is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    tools:context="musync.demo_app.ListingMusic">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why don't you have onCreate? and why don't you use setContentView? This is why you can't use it. Hope this helps.

Comment: show  you logcat msg

Comment: onCreate is in the code but i was not able to post my question here cause the code was too lomg so i replaced it with <useless code> tag but this is in my project

Comment: XML: https://pastebin.com/x48pyfNH
Java: https://pastebin.com/kejN6ivd
Manifest XML: https://pastebin.com/qRun6j0M

Answer (score -1):

You are missing your onCreate() ? add the onCreate function in your java file and type `R.id.listview` only after `setContentView()` function is called.

Comment: do not  post answer which is already mentioned  in comment .use comment section

Comment: XML: https://pastebin.com/x48pyfNH
Java: https://pastebin.com/kejN6ivd
Manifest XML: https://pastebin.com/qRun6j0M

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
```

To:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: do not  post answer which is already mentioned  in comment .use comment section

Comment: I just delete it to post it here. The code was too long but this code you wrote is in my projext

Comment: @LaveauAnderson Then how could we know that you have deleted it?

Comment: Sorry i was in hurry so i forgot to write it in

Comment: @Tej , I thought that he is new that's why added this answer clearly. Not necessary to Downvote all answers!

Comment: Can you add your code and Error here @LaveauAnderson

Comment: XML: https://pastebin.com/x48pyfNH
Java: https://pastebin.com/kejN6ivd
Manifest XML: https://pastebin.com/qRun6j0M

Comment: @LaveauAnderson Look at this edited answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47968023/6314513